# match method in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, named-routing

I'm trying to follow this tutorial [here](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec:rails_routes) but the tutorial seems to use this "match" function.

```
match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
```

Whenever, I do the same, I get this error from the server:

> undefined method `match' for main:Object

How can I edit the routes.rb file such that:

1. it will route from a long file path
   to a short one (eg. /pages/about to
   /about)
2. I can have a "about_path"
   variable that I can link to ( eg:
   <%= link_to "About", about_path %> )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using Ruby on Rails 3? The `match` router syntax is for Rails 3 only. For previous versions you can define a named route:

```
map.about '/about', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'about'
```

Comment: Apparently, I'm not using RoR 3, but I did try your method and it will shorten the path if I do map.about 'about', ... However, will this create a "about_path" that I can refer to globally from any page?

Comment: Yes, it will provide an `about_path` helper.

Answer (score 0):

that syntax is for the upcoming Rails3 (actually in beta4 but it's yet adopted for production, if you know what you're doing :P)

you should use this for rails 2.3:

```
map.about '/about', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'about'
```

this works if you have an action called 'about' that renders a specific page.
otherwise, if 'about' is a simple page that you fetch from a 'show' action, passing an ID or a PERMALINK (eg: you're using permalink_fu plugin), then the right syntax is:

```
map.about '/about', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'about', :id => 'page_id_or_permalink'
```

this solution it's not the best: if you change the permalink or delete/re-create the page with a different id, then you must update the routes. by the way it works as you asked.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with:

```
  map.connect '/page', :controller => 'page2', :action => 'index'
```

so, in the URL I just redirect to `http://x.x.x.x/page` and RoR is really loading `http://x.x.x.x/page2/index.html.erb`

Best Regards,

Iván Carrasco Q.